# SpringBootTest does not load context

Tags: groovy, resttemplate, spock, spring-boot-test

I am trying to write functional-test case for a rest controller. According to plan I'd like to start application and using TestRestTemplate call appropriate endpoint. Unfortunately, I am unable to do so because occurring error:

```
Cannot invoke method exchange() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method exchange() on null object
...
```

I can't figure out why and it is the only error message that I get. I feel confused ://

In addition, I'm using Spock framework for testing.

Thanks for your help in advance.

gradle.build

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'org.unbroken-dome.test-sets' version '4.0.0'
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/test.gradle"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.6.3')

    testImplementation(group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '3.0.9')
    testImplementation(group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '2.0-groovy-3.0')
    testImplementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.6.3')

}
// some more usual Gradle stuff
```

test.gradle

```
testSets {
    integrationTest { dirName = 'integration-test' }
    functionalTest { dirName = 'functional-test' }
}

integrationTest {
    mustRunAfter(test)
}

check.dependsOn(integrationTest)

functionalTest {
    mustRunAfter(integrationTest)
}

check.dependsOn(functionalTest)

tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

GreetingControllerSpec

```
package tchorzyksen

/* imports */
 
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class GreetingControllerSpec extends Specification {
    
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate

    void "get greeting"() {
        when:
        ResponseEntity<GreetingEntity> response = get("/greeting", GreetingEntity.class)

        then:
        response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK
    }

    protected <T> ResponseEntity<T> get(String uri, Class<T> responseClass) {
        return testRestTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, responseClass, [:])
    }

}
```

MyWs.java

```
package tchorzyksen;

/* imports */

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyWs {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyWs.class, args);
  }
}
```

and GreetingController

```
package tchorzyksen.ui.model.controller;

/* imports */

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

  private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
  private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

  @GetMapping("/greeting")
  public ResponseEntity<GreetingEntity> greeting(
      @RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
        new GreetingEntity(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate
```

Enough

```
private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
```

Comment: That's not a valid answer for me. You are correct this way it is possible to inject dependency manually. But what is the point of doing that ? According to documentation I should be able to Autowire TestRestTemplate as it comes form SpringBootTest. Besides what is the point of testing application which did not start ://.

Answer (score 0):

For all people interested in solution to this question. We are missing one dependency here

```
testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-spring', version: '2.1-M2-groovy-3.0'
```

Which basically makes it possible to write tests in Spock and use spring test context.

Save yourselfs guys it took me 4 hours to discover (very sad face) ://

Comment: I have heard you. Maybe [this documentation pull request](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/pull/1422) can improve the situation for future readers of the otherwise excellent [Spock manual](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1-M2/all_in_one.html#_modules).